# In phpinfo()'s output, which value is the one used?

Tags: php

Here's a snippet of my phpinfo() output:

```
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 512M => 128M
```

Which one gets used? The first or last?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using in this case?

Comment: @IpsitaRout version 5.3.23

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is the local value, the second is the global value. The local value overrides the global value and is set within PHP, HTACCESS, etc. whereas the global value is set within php.ini. To answer your question, the first value is used.

Comment: Thank you. Though I do wonder how I am supposed to know that. Is this a normal convention?